# Access Violate Writing Exception Using Python Ctypes on VB6-Based DLL

Tags: python, exception, dll, ctypes

This might seem redundant or very simple to ask but I could not figure out this reading similar posts. Hope its a fixable issue.

I have a WINDLL created based on vb6 code which containes 3 public functions as below:

```
PrintTitlesName(MyPath as String)
CreateDllFile(MyPath as String)
```

The description of these two functions are as below:

> **PrintTitlesName:** print titles of the variables that you need to use in
>   the project folder (MyPath) with extension (.MyTitles).
>   **CreatDllFile:** Create a file in the project folder (MyPath) with extension
>   (.DLLFile).

Acording to what I read about CTypes, I came up with following code to use the DLL:

```
import ctypes
NNDLL = ctypes.WinDLL ("D:/ISI/tmp/NN DLL/NNetApply.dll")

# ------------------------------------------------------
#            PrintTitlesName  (MyAddress As String)
# ------------------------------------------------------
TitlesApiProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p)
TitlesApiParams = (1, "p1", 0),
TitlesApi = TitlesApiProto (("PrintTitlesName", NNDLL), TitlesApiParams)

# ------------------------------------------------------
#          Call Functions
# ------------------------------------------------------
p1 = ctypes.c_char_p ("D:/ISI/tmp/NN DLL/Demo/")
TitlesApi (p1)
```

Running the code above, leads to Windows Error which seems to be some illegal operation by DLL. However, I cannot put my finger on what is wrong and I would appreciate any help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ISI\tmp\NN DLL\Test DLL.py", line 98, in <module>
    TitlesApi (p1)
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000050
```

Comment: Doesn't VB6 create a COM DLL? Look into using comtypes (based on ctypes) or PyWin32's win32com.

Comment: I tried comtypes and it cannot even load the DLL. I am leaned toward that the DLL I have is a win DLL. The error happen only at very last line of code above when I call the function.

Comment: COM usually works through the registry, where the DLL is registered using regsvr32.exe. The are examples for using COM interfaces in the [comtypes docs](https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes).

Comment: VB6 definitely, positively, creates COM DLLs. If the DLL is truly a VB6 DLL, it is a COM DLL. Try registering the DLL with regsvr32 - if registration succeeds, it is a COM DLL.

Comment: @MarkJ: I got the following Error message running `regsvr32 NNetApply.dll`:  **The module "NNetApply.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005.**

Comment: @MarkJ: I also tried the options `regsvr32 /i /n NNetApply.dll` and the returned error was: **The module "NNetApply.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllInstall was not found. Make sure that "NNetApply.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.**

Comment: Are you running regsvr32 as administrator?

Comment: @MarkJ Thank you. You were right, it worked as admin. I am still trying to browse for how to access functions inside the COM DLL.